# Calculating length of field using Arcade?

Tags: expression, arcade

I have data with this format: **4024-457** and I need to separate the left and right portions from the **'-'**. The data is not always in that proportion (4 numbers left and 3 to the right) so I need to calculate the position of **'-'** to extract both sides.

In the case of left numbers I used this expression:

```
Left($feature.R_ROL,Find('-', $feature.R_ROL))
```

But i don't find the way to extract the right portion of the main data. In ArcMap I used a VBscript expresion like this.

```
Right( [R_ROL] , Len( [R_ROL])- (InStr( [R_ROL] , "-")))
```

I can't find anything like the Len function to calculate the total lenght of the field to recreate something like the above. I'm still new to Arcade.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I have found how to do this. If anyone is interested, the right portion of the expression was calculated this way:

```
Right($feature.R_ROL,(Count($feature.R_ROL) - (Find('-', $feature.R_ROL) +1)))
```

**R_ROL** is the field to search for and **-** is the character used to calculate right and left portion.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do the following:

```
Back(Split($feature.R_ROL, "-"));
```